# Questions on the Empty Set $\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Comment on following (where $\emptyset$ denotes Empty Set)**
$1.\qquad\emptyset \subseteq\emptyset$
$2.\qquad \emptyset \subseteq \{\emptyset\}$
$3.\qquad\emptyset \in \emptyset$
$4.\qquad \emptyset \in \{\emptyset\}$

I know the answer to just first problem, and confused on remaining. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @alexqwx thanks for the edit

Comment: @alexqwx Now it appears to be four times the same question! I think that the edit certainly got $3.$ and $4.$ wrong (it should be $\in$).

Comment: Yep- just copy and paste `$1. \varnothing \subset\varnothing$

$2. \varnothing
\subset \{\varnothing\}$

$3. \varnothing \in \varnothing$

$4. \varnothing \in\{\varnothing\}$`
 into the question because I can't edit it again.

Comment: **HINT:** This, and other very similar questions, were asked several times before.

Comment: @downvoter why the downvote,  i didn't knew the latex

Comment: I think that maybe someone thought that I was the downvoter, because I somehow got two downvotes around the time this was upvoted back up. So just to clarify this, no I didn't vote (up, down, or otherwise) on this thread.

Comment: @AsafKaragila just to clarify i was not the downvoter of your posts, your answers are always phenonemal :D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $\emptyset$ does not contain any elements so:

1) no element can be found in $\emptyset$ that is *not* an element of $\emptyset$ so indeed $\emptyset\subseteq\emptyset$

2) no element can be found in $\emptyset$ that is *not* an element of $\{\emptyset\}$ so indeed $\emptyset\subseteq\{\emptyset\}$

3) $x\notin\emptyset$ is true for any $x$ so also for $x=\emptyset$

4) Set $\{\emptyset\}$ contains $\emptyset$ as element, as in general set $\{x\}$ contains $x$ as element.

---

**edit**

The four statements above are okay. If $\subset$ replaces $\subseteq$ in 1) and 2), and stands for *proper subset* then the adapted 1) is not true anymore, but 2) still is.

Also it should be noted that lots of authors use $\subset$ and $\subsetneq$
instead of $\subseteq$ and $\subset$ respectively. Always check on what side
the author is.

Comment: so only third is false rest are true

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you sir, very helpful

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: @drhab Why is 1 true? how can $\varnothing \subsetneq \varnothing$ be true?

Comment: @drhab i have edited the question, does that change ur answer, as i see u have given answer to the edited question, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Shobhit I made an edit and hope to cover the whole case now.

Comment: @drhab yes sir it does, thanks for the clarification and the answer.

Comment: @alexqwx You are correct in doubting that $\emptyset\subsetneq\emptyset$. I hope my edit makes things more clear.

Comment: About the ambiguity of $\subset$ and $\subsetneq$ versus $\subseteq$ and $\subset$: I use (and I urge everybody to use) $\subsetneq$ and $\subseteq$, so that the ambiguity disappears.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I hope you have a wise audience :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Three of the four statements are true.

Comment: @Alizter: No it's not.

Comment: While correct, it is hardly a helpful answer.

Comment: @Alizter: I disagree and stand by that three of the four statements are true.

Comment: @Alizter mind posting your own answer to clear things, thanks

Comment: Alizter, $\subset$ is not the same as $\large\subsetneq$ in all contexts.

Comment: Ok. I see what you're saying.  I had understood the question to be about general subsets, not necessarily proper subsets.  I wonder which way it is in the OP's original problem.

Comment: @amWhy OK. I retract my comment. Though the notation was a bit ambiguous

Comment: @amWhy Is it not? I thought that $$\subsetneq $$ was just another way of (emphatically) writing $$\subset \quad ,$$ analogous to $$\lneq $$ being a more emphatic version of $$<$$.

Comment: It's ambiguous, actually. Take Walter Rudin, who uses $\subset$ to mean $\subseteq$