# Which of these are true about the empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Curious which of the following are true.

$\emptyset \in \{\emptyset\} $

Comment: There are hundred's of duplicates here for it at this site. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913868/questions-on-the-empty-set-varnothing?rq=1) and the ones linked at the right margin.

Comment: Whoah really ? ._. I thought that...
3 is the same as {∅} ⊆ {∅} which I would think is true. 
4 is the same as ∅ ∈{∅, {∅}} which I would think is true (since ∅ is an element of every set)
5 I figured they are the same based on what I thought about #4

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know there are many related questions and I did read 5 before posting

Comment: Try to write down the arguments showing why for you 3,4,5 must hold... A simple check is: count the elements of the two sets.

Comment: For 3.. {{∅}} ⊆ {∅} is true and would wouldnt {∅,{∅}} = {∅} (since every set contains the empty set whether explicitly stated or not) which would imply that 3 is true?

Comment: Downvotes are because this is a PSQ, Problem Statement Question, where you didn't bother to show us what you tried. Edit your question (don't do it in the comments!) as suggested by Mauro, tell us what you think and why, and I'll upvote to compensate.

Comment: Ah thank you for explaining that, still new here :)

Comment: 3) NO. The left-side set has **two** elements (the empty set and the one-element set $\{ \emptyset \}$) while the right-side set has only one (the empty set). Thus, by extensionality, they **cannot** be equal.

Comment: @SimpleMind Somos and I visibly agree on what was your issue. Now that you better understand, can you rethink your answers by yourself? (Mauro makes very good points by the way, I advise to pay attention to them)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518839/set-membership-and-inclusion-confusion/518885#518885

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are confusing two similar but different relations.
One set may be an **element** of another set.
One set may be a **subset** of another set. These are two
different relations between sets. For example, the empty
set is a subset of every set, but is **not** an element
of every set. You wrote

> since every set contains the empty set whether explicitly stated or not

and also

> Since the empty set is part of every set, whether implicitly or not,

which is true **only** if "contains" is used in the sense of subset.
Same thing if "part" is used in the sense of subset.

Sometimes a set with one element is wrongly equated to the element
itself. Thus, stating that $\,x\,$ is an element of set $\,A\,$ is
equivalent to stating that $\,\{x\}\,$ is a subset of $\,A.\,$
However, $\,x\,$ is **not** the same as $\,\{x\}\,$  and the relation
"element of" is not the same as "subset of". Both statements are valid
ways of stating that $\,x\,$ is contained in $\,A\,$, but using two
different relations.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for updating the question. Now that we know how you thought, we can easily point out the problem in your thought process. You say

> Since the empty set is part of every set, whether implicitly or not

And that's exactly the issue. As Mauro said in the comments, "Emptyset is **subset** of every set". This does **not** imply that "Emptyset is an *element* of every set", and there's no implicit-ness about it.

$$
\varnothing \subseteq A \; {\;\not\!\!\!\!\implies} \varnothing \in A 
$$

Comment: Ah, I see, I thought the implication made it so; thanks for detailing this!!